# VSCode emmet issue after changing case for file name

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, emmet

I am new to using VSCode and emmet for expanding filenames, etc.

Currently, I'm working on a React project and found an issue where, for example:

1. I create a files named, say, `myfile.jsx` for my `MyFile` component
2. Realize I want the file name capitalized to match the component name, so I rename it to `MyFile.jsx`
3. When trying to use emmet to import the file to use the component in, say, my `App.js` it imports the old filename `myfile.jsx` (without the updated casing).

In other words, emmet is not picking up in the change in casing for file names.

Is there a way to somehow refresh the cache for emmet / have this update without having to restart VSCode?

Thanks!